# JOIN multiple unions using a loop

Tags: mysql, loops

I'm facing the following issue:
I have a JSON array such as this:

```
[{"from":"09:25","to":"14:00"},{"from":"15:05","to":"16:10"},{"from":"17:40","to":"17:50"},{"from":"19:00","to":"19:10"},{"from":"19:30","to":"19:50"}]
```

And I want to have a MySQL query that returns a row for each of the intervals, containing the '**from**' and '**to**' as columns.
So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    idx,
    REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')), CONCAT('$.from')), '"', '') AS 'from',
    REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')), CONCAT('$.to')), '"', '') AS 'to',
    json
FROM test.json
JOIN ( 
  SELECT  0 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  1 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  2 AS idx UNION    
  SELECT  3 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  4
  ) AS indexes
```

And it does work. I get the following result:
[image]
*this is the desired output. The problem is the set number of SELECTS in the join.*

The issue is that I have to do this:

```
  SELECT  0 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  1 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  2 AS idx UNION    
  SELECT  3 AS idx UNION
  SELECT  4
```

to insert as many 'idx' as there are items in the JSON array. Is there any way to create do this with a loop? The count of the items will be stored in a separate column, '**howmany**' in the table that contains the JSON.

This is how the table I extract data from looks like:
[image]

I've tried iterating with a while:

```
declare counter int unsigned default 0;
SELECT 
    idx,
    REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')), CONCAT('$.from')), '"', '') AS 'from',
    REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')), CONCAT('$.to')), '"', '') AS 'to',
    json
FROM test.json
JOIN ( 
  (while counter < howmany do
    SELECT counter AS idx UNION
    set counter=counter+1;
  end WHILE)
  ) AS indexes
```

and it fails. I am 100% certain that the way I tried is not the way to do it, but I am out of ideas.

**Edit:** I think it's worth mentioning that we cannot use JSON_TABLE as our MariaDB version is a slightly earlier one than when JSON_TABLE was introduced.

**Edit2:** I'm using Apache XAMPP's MySQL server.

```
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $
```

MariaDB version **10.3.32**

Comment: (1) provide precise MySQL version. (2) Show desired output for shown JSON.

Comment: @Akina the desired output from JSON is shown in the first image, but I just want to do it without using a set number of "SELECT number AS idx UNION".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT id,
           jsonvalue,
           0 num,
           JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsonvalue, CONCAT('$[', 0, '].from'))) `from`,
           JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsonvalue, CONCAT('$[', 0, '].to'))) `to`
    FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,
           jsonvalue,
           1 + num,
           JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsonvalue, CONCAT('$[', 1 + num, '].from'))),
           JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jsonvalue, CONCAT('$[', 1 + num, '].to')))
    FROM cte
    WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jsonvalue, CONCAT('$[', 1 + num, '].from')) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id,
       `from`,
       `to`
FROM cte;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=58b22124e88fd8bb1fee8282f01523c6)

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thank you so much; I've spent the entire day trying to find a way to do this. I'm still a beginner regarding SQL but I'll definitely research the CTE and other things used here!